# Obtaining angle of rotation from eigenvalues of the rotation matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose we have a 2D rotation matrix. If we plot eigenvalues on the complex plane, angle of rotation is connected to eigenvalues -- larger rotations have eigenvalues further away from 1.

[image]

To extend this to higher dimensions, I want to know the following:

Given a fixed [generic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_property) orthogonal matrix $A$, and a random Gaussian vector $x$, can we get $z$, the expected value of cosine of the angle between $x$ and $Ax$, from eigenvalues of $A$?

There appears to be square-root-like relationship, if rotation is small, all eigenvalues are close to $1$, as we increase $z$, eigenvalues get further away from $1$.
[image]

This plot is made by taking orthogonal component of QR decomposition of $I+\epsilon G$ for random Gaussian matrix $G$ and varying values of $\epsilon$. Estimating angle of rotation by trying it on random Gaussian vectors, and plotting against arg of the eigenvalues.

[Notebook](https://www.wolframcloud.com/obj/yaroslavvb/newton/forum-rotational-eval-angles.nb)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the expected value of the cosine is uniquely determined by the eigenvalues, being the average of the real parts.

We can decompose $A$ as rotations $R_i$ of mutually orthogonal 2D subspaces $V_i$ (and the identity or reflection along a 1D space if the dimension is odd).
Let $\lambda_i, \overline{\lambda_i}$ be the eigenvalues of $A$ corresponding to $R_i$ and let $x_i$ be the projection of $x$ onto $V_i$.
Then $x^TAx = \sum_i x_i^T R_i x_i$.
For $v_i$ uniformly distributed on $\{v\in\mathbb{R}^2: \|v\|_2 = 1\}$, we have $\mathbb{E}[v_i^T R_i v_i] = \Re(\lambda_i)$, so with $x$ uniformly distributed on the sphere, $$\mathbb{E}[x^TAx] = \frac{2}{n}\sum_i \Re(\lambda_i),$$ where $n$ is the dimension.

Comment: Oh that's great, so simple!